# Is it possible to add the elements in the array during iteration?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, sorting, stdvector

I want to sort the elements.

For example: Initially, I get `5` elements and sorted it.
The question is the next `5` elements should add to the previous `5` elements and then it should perform sorting.

Is any inbuilt function to perform in vector this?

Comment: You can sort a vector with `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());`. Just call that after getting your additional elements. But then again I might be misunderstanding your question, so it would be helpful if you posted your code, your expected result and your current result.

Comment: Can you make an example with pseudocode?

Answer (score 5):

> Is any inbuilt function to perform this using vector in c++?

`std::vector` is a sequence container which **does not perform any automatic sorting** unless you sort them using `std::sort`.

You might be looking for *[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)* if the elements are unique or *[`std::multiset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)* if the elements are
not unique to do this behavior. The sorting is don by *[compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)* function as per standard requirements.

Answer (score 4):

If you insert elements into a *currently sorted* vector at the first position after all the elements they are greater than, then the vector remains sorted.

You can find the position with [`std::lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound)

```
std::vector<int> currently_sorted{ 1, 2, 5, 6, 7 };
for (auto i : { 3, 4, 10, 9, 8 })
{
     auto it = std::lower_bound(currently_sorted.begin(), currently_sorted.end(), i);
     currently_sorted.insert(it, i);
}

assert(std::is_sorted(currently_sorted.begin(), currently_sorted.end()));
```